# add trace/breakpoint while already in R's browser

Tags: r, debugging, trace

**Edit**: for the record, the accepted answer has a significant down-fall in that it re-executes the first *n* lines of code in the function when re-debugged. This might be okay, but when those lines of code include side-effects (e.g., database updates) and/or long-time calculations, it becomes obvious what is happening. I do not believe R provides the ability to do it "properly" (as some other languages do). Bummer.

---

Some debuggers allow you to dynamically add breakpoints while in the debugger. Is that functionality possible in R? An example:

```
quux <- function(..)
{ # line 1
  "line 2"
  "line 3"
  "line 4"
  "line 5"
  "line 6"
}

trace("quux", tracer = browser, at = 3)
# [1] "quux"
quux()
# Tracing quux() step 3 
# Called from: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
# Browse[1]> 
# debug: [1] "line 3"
```

While debugging, I believe I want to jump ahead in the code. Imagine the function has a few hundred lines of code, and I'd prefer to not step through them.

I'd like to be able to do this, and jump from the current line to the next interesting line, but unfortunately it just continues out of the function.

```
# Browse[2]>
trace("quux", tracer = browser, at = 5)
# [1] "quux"
# Browse[2]>
c    
# [1] "line 6"
# # (out of the debugger)
```

The `trace` call while in the debugger merely added the breakpoint to the original (global) function, as shown if I immediately call the function again:

```
quux()
# Tracing quux() step 5 
# Called from: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
# Browse[1]> 
# debug: [1] "line 5"
```

I tried setting both at once (`at=c(3,5)`) while inside the browser, but this just sets those lines for when I exit the debugger and call the function again.

I'm guessing this has to do with the function to which `trace` is attaching the breakpoint. Looking into `trace` (and `.TraceWithMethods`), I think I need to be setting `where`, but I cannot figure out how to get it to set a new breakpoint/trace on the in-debugging function.

(The larger picture is that I'm troubleshooting a function that is dealing with a kafka-led stream of data. My two options are currently (a) restart the function with the more appropriate trace, but this requires me to purge and restart the data stream as well; or (b) go line-by-line in the debugger, tedious when there are many hundreds of lines of code.)

Comment: I suspect this isn't directly possible since tracing/debugging mechanisms rely on creating new functions with debugging enabled.  What you might be able to do is if the line you want to skip to is itself a function call, then `debug` that function.  e.g. in `{line1;line2;line3;my_fun();line4}` you can run `debug(my_fun)` followed by `c` at the browse prompt and you'll skip straight to the contents `my_fun`.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I suspect. Your suggestion works if there is a function at the next breakpoint. Thanks, @BrodieG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be kind of a solution. First do as in your post:

```
> quux <- function(..)
+ { # line 1
+   x <- 1   # added for illustration
+   "line 3"
+   "line 4"
+   "line 5"
+   print(x) # added for illustration
+   "line 7"
+   "line 8"
+ }
> 
> trace("quux", tracer = browser, at = 4)
[1] "quux"
> quux()
Tracing quux() step 4 
Called from: eval(expr, p)
Browse[1]> n
debug: [1] "line 4"
```

Next, we do as follows in the debugger:

```
Browse[2]> this_func <- eval(match.call()[[1]])       # find out which funcion is called
Browse[2]> formals(this_func) <- list()               # remove arguments
Browse[2]> body(this_func) <- body(this_func)[-(2:4)] # remove lines we have evalutaed   
Browse[2]> trace("this_func", tracer = browser, 
+                at = 8 - 4 + 1)                      # at new line - old trace point
Tracing function "this_func" in package "base"
[1] "this_func"
Browse[2]> this_func                                  # print for illustration
function () 
{
    "line 5"
    print(x)
    "line 7"
    "line 8"
}
Browse[2]> environment(this_func) <- environment()    # change enviroment so x is present
Browse[2]> this_func()                                # call this_func
[1] 1
[1] "line 8"
```

The downside is that we end back at `"line 5"` in the original call to `quux` after we exit from the call to `this_func`. Further, we have to keep track of the last `at` value. We may be able to get this from another function?

Comment: Very interesting, thanks Benjamin! I'll play around with this for a bit.

Comment: Is it also a downside that this re-executes the first *n* lines of code? For instance, if any of the first few lines included any side-effect (e.g., database updates), this would not be a viable option. I still find it an interesting work-around, thanks Benjamin.

Comment: Thanks again, Benjamin, finally giving you props for the answer.